# [mutableArray initWithArray: [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]] compile is right,but encounter error while running

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

```
[mutableArray initWithArray: [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];
```

`componentsSeparatedByString` returns a `NSArray *`, and `initWithArray` accepts an `NSArray *`.

However, when I run this code there is some error. What's the issue?

Comment: Edit your question and add the stacktrace.

Comment: Could you please provide the error.Because below given are the answers.But I want to know the error description.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot the call to `alloc`:

```
// Assuming:
NSMutableArray *mutableArray;

// Then:
mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];
```

Alternatively:

```
mutableArray = [[str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] mutableCopy];
```

Comment: No need to do mutable copy as you have declared the Object as NSMutableArray.So you can add or removed object.

Comment: @iPhoneDev You mean just use `copy` instead of `mutableCopy`?  That will cause a runtime error.

Comment: my mistake.I thought you have allocated the mutableArray then used the component..... method.

Comment: i hava alloc NSString *str = @"I feel good";
        NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        mutableArray = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

Comment: @吴志坚 That is still broken code; you are assigning an `NSArray` to an `NSMutableArray` and will get a runtime error when you attempt `addObject` on it.  Have you tried the code I provide in my answer?

Comment: @trojanfoe no not that one is broken code.Yes it give warning.But the cord will still work.You can check this in  Xcode.

Comment: @iPhoneDev I did check; I posted a gist of the test (see above).

Comment: @trojanfoe there seems are some rule,if i want to use initXXX method,i hava to use it with alloc in a line;